# Algorithm and Design for developing a exact text system

Tags: exact-match

We have millions of documents consisting of many paragraphs. The requirement is to develop a exact search system on top of this corpus. The search string will typically start from the beginning of a paragraph and may extend to two or more paragraphs. 
What data structure and algorithm will be used to store persist the data in this system
It is to be noted that the pace of addition of documents in much slower as compared to the pace of search query across the pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually Parse Millions of Records by yourself it will be a tedious and time consuming task.

You can Use APACHE Lucene Engine to parse the document for you. 
If you dont know about Lucene, it is a full-featured text search engine library that enables  full-text search, especially cross-platform.

Check out : http://lucene.apache.org